# A free control like ObjectListView?

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, gridview

I need something like `ObjectListView` (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), but it *must* be free and LGPL, BSD or some license that allow its use in commercial applications.

Answer (score 7):

*I post it as an answer, instead of an update to the question, as did the OP, who is no longer active...*

If somebody wants to know, the Phillip's response:

> Hi,
>
> To use ObjectListView commercially, companies normally buy a license.
>   A license to use ObjectListView commercially is 100 euros for small
>   companies or 500 euros for medium sized companies. This license gives
>   the company permission to use ObjectListView in any and all of its
>   closed source applications. The license fee covers the current and all
>   future versions -- there are no upgrade fees.
>
> The restrictions on the license are that the company cannot
>   redistribute the source code, and they may not claim to have written
>   ObjectListView.
>
> You are free to modify the source as you need to, obviously. If you
>   find bugs, please report them at the SourceForge tracker, and I will
>   fix them.
>
> If you want to buy a license, send me the name of the company and
>   whether it is a small or medium sized company, and I will send you a
>   "bill" through PayPal.
>
> v2.4.1 is just about to be released. It fixes improves text filtering
>   and adds images and vertical text to the list header (plus the normal
>   number of bug fixes).
>
> Regards, Phillip

Answer (score 2):

From their FAQ:

> However, if you wish to use this code in a commercial application, please contact me: phillip_piper@bigfoot.com

Did you try contacting the author?